# why MVC Telerik grid custom ajax binding dos not load the result in a grid but ajax request and json is ok?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have MVC web application project and i use  Telerik mvc grid in one popup window .I want to sorting and filtering worked by ajax ,then i use custom binding ajax in Telerik web site. 
[custom ajax binding](http://telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/custombinding)
when i run my app and filter something or sorting  not change happen. my grid data are fixed ,and dos not any change, but when i checked by fiddler ajax request is ok and json object is full and its ok but the grid data is fixed.i don't know why and what is wrong in my code ?thanks in advance .

this is my view code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Raja.DomainClasses.Entities.PartBooklet>
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("PartBookletGrid")

        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.PartCode).Width(150).Title("کد کتابچه قطعه").Template(@<text><div><a class="popup" onclick="SendValuePartBooklet(this.innerHTML)">@item.PartCode</a></div></text>);
            columns.Bound(o => o.Title).Width(100).Title("نام کتابچه قطعه");
            columns.Bound(o => o.PartGroup1.GroupName).Title("دسته/گروه قطعه");
        })
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_CustomBinding","Shared"))
        .Pageable(settings => settings.Total((int)ViewData["total"]))
        .EnableCustomBinding(true)
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .Groupable()
        .Localizable("fa-IR")
        .Footer(false)
) 
@{ Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Globalization(true); }

and this is controller:
        public ActionResult PartBookletPopUp()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
        //
        private static int count;     

        [GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
        public ActionResult _CustomBinding(GridCommand command)
        {
            IEnumerable data = GetData(command);
            List<PartBooklet> partBookletList = new List<PartBooklet>();

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                partBookletList.Add((PartBooklet)item);
            }

            ViewData["total"] = GetCount();
            data = (IEnumerable)_PartBookletService.ManuallyProxyCreationDisableForDBContext(partBookletList);


            return View("PartBookletGridPopup",  new GridModel
                            {
                                Data = partBookletList,
                                Total = count
                            });
        }
        private IEnumerable GetData(GridCommand command)
        {

            IQueryable<PartBooklet> data = _PartBookletService.GetQuery(p => p.Id > 0);
            //Apply filtering
            data = data.ApplyFiltering(command.FilterDescriptors);
            //Apply sorting
            data = data.ApplySorting(command.GroupDescriptors, command.SortDescriptors);  
            //Apply paging
            //data = data.ApplyPaging(command.Page, command.PageSize);

            return data.ToList();
        }

        private int GetCount()
        {
            IQueryable<PartBooklet> data = _PartBookletService.GetQuery(p => p.Id > 0);

            return data.Count();

        }


        public ActionResult PartBookletGridPopup()
        {
            IEnumerable data = GetData(new GridCommand());

            ViewData["total"] = GetCount();
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-IR");
            //List<PartBooklet> Data = new List<PartBooklet>();
            //Data = (List<PartBooklet>)_PartBookletService.GetList();

          //  return View(Data);
            return View(data);
        }
```

Comment: does not any body know about my question ???